# Desktop crash after login (16.4.3)

Tags: nvidia, xorg, crash

for a week or two, when I boot Ubuntu (16.4.3) Unity seems to crash just after loggin in.
When it comes the only way to recover my desktop is launching in recovery, run a set of commands found on internet forums (i'm not sure which one really fix the issue) and restart. Interesting thing is that Unity and Gnome crashs with an empty desktop (I just see the mouse cursor) but enlightment let me see the desktop but crashs anyway a bit later.
It crash with both nvidia and Xorg drivers.
When the issue is fixed, Ubuntu seems to work normally, but several days later it crashs again.
I don't find what's wrong in logs but I'm not an expert.

My computer is an Asus ux501 VW-FI232T (I7 - GTX960M - 4k screen)

Comment: Can you add the commands you ran from those sites.

Comment: `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` `setsid compiz --replace` `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I tried also to restart lightdm and i switched graphic driver (in both directions depending the initial situation).

Comment: Finaly this is the command that work : sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg but at restart it crashs again.

Answer (score 0):

My desktop was last week gone too after updating several programs I installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome3 desktop. But after using the following commands it installed again and was fixed.

The command to reinstall the Unity desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

The commands for Gnome3 which you can use as default too on top of your Unity:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

***Do you mean that you used these commands already? Just to make things more clear about your question.***

Otherwise this would probably solve (partly) your problem. After this you can just run your Ubuntu in normal mode.

Comment: It didn't worked. In fact at each ubuntu reboot I lose my desktop. reinstalling unbutu-desktop worked but I rebooted and then the crash appeared again. After that re-installing ubuntu-desktop had no effect.